# Find how many subsets in a set have a target sum

Tags: java

Given an array of `int`s and a target value, find how many subsets in the array add to the target value.

I keep getting funky numbers when I run it...is anything wrong?

```
public int findGoal(int[] anArray,int index, int current, int goal, String result){

    //Base case: At the end of the array
    if (anArray.length <= index || current>goal) {
        return count;
    }

    //Recursive case: If not at end iterate
    for (int i = index; i < anArray.length; i++) {          
        if (current + anArray[i] == goal)   {
            count++;
        } else if (current + anArray[i] < goal) {
            count = findGoal(anArray, i + 1, current + anArray[i], goal, result + " " + anArray[i]);
        }               
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: you should show how you are invoking this function also

Comment: I'm using another class to call the method using a scanner that asks for the numbers in the array and the target value

Comment: If you're getting funky numbers, something is wrong. Intermixing iteration and recursion generally means you haven't thought something through enough. Have you tried printing out which values you're selecting, so you can see whether you're actually examining every subset and doing so only once?

Comment: @user3144709 what I mean is, give us an example of the parameters being passed to this function, as it seems like using incorrect values for `index` or `current` or `goal` would yield bad answers.